# CSS margin calculated correctly but displayed wrong. Resizing window corrects it

Tags: html, css

I have two tables floated side by side in a parent div. The leftmost table has a margin-right of 10%. As you can see in the image, the margin is calculated correctly (in this case, the parent is 850px, and the metrics inspector shows an 85px margin) but when drawn, is incorrect (much smaller.)

Resizing the window to make it redraw immediately fixes it. What is going on here!?

[image]

HTML:

```
<table id="subscriptions" class="data">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Subscriptions
        <span id="remaining">Remaining</span></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Spin Classes</td>
        <td class="right">3</td>
        <td class="right"><a href="REDEEM">Redeem</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Spin Classes</td>
        <td class="right">3</td>
        <td class="right"><a href="REDEEM">Redeem</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="redeemed" class="data">
    <tr>
        <th>Redeemed Items</th>
        <th class="right">Redeemed</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Spin Class</td>
        <td class="right">3/3/13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Spin Class</td>
        <td class="right">3/3/13</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#subscriptions, #redeemed {
width: 45%;
float: left;
clear: both;
margin: 25px 10% 0 0;
}

#redeemed {
    clear: none;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please copy your relevant code here.  Without it, we can't possibly help.

Comment: I think it may have to do with the fact that for #redeemed, you clear:both and then clear: none. If clear:both is what you really want then clear: none is overriding it.

Comment: Could you make a [codepen](http://www.codepen.io) or [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Here's a codepen, though the error isn't reproducible there, maybe because it's in a frame? When it loads, though, you can still see the second table "jump" right when it correctly draws the margin. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avczf

Answer (score 0):

I think if you get rid of both the `clear` lines in the css it might fix it?

Comment: No dice, removing them entirely messes up the correct layout but even so the margin is drawn wrong.